# How to hide one row in a rowgroup?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report in SSRS 2008 that has the following structure:

```
List
  Tablix
    Row Group
      Row1
        Field
      Row2
        Subreport
```

Is it possible to completely hide the first row in the row group, based on some condition?

I can hide the row, but the empty row still takes up space, I want the empty row to take up no space at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the answer is given in the discussion that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3214326/7922) links to:

> Try to set the Hidden property of the Static Row Group under the Details Group, in this case the whole row will disappear instead of the content of the textboxes.If you are using Report Builder, you need to switch to Advanced Mode (make sure that the Properties and the Grouping windows are displayed, go to the upper right side of the Grouping window and press the black triangle), click on the second "Static" item under the "(Details)" group and you can set the Hidden property on the Properties window.

However, this causes an exception when trying to export the report as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an expression for the visibility of row.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, on the `static` row group, as explained by the quote in my own answer. However, as that same answer states, this causes a rendering exception to be thrown when trying to export the report as PDF (or any other format for that matter). I cannot figure out how to prevent this exception from being thrown.